# how to redirect all 302's to a different url as 404's using htaccess or apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

i am wondering how to redirect all 302's to a different url as 404's using htaccess or apache?

i prefer the htaccess method

maybe something like `Redirect 302 /PATH_TO_REDIRECT NEW_LOCATION_URI`

but how do i tell the new url to be a `404`

any ideas?

Comment: 404 means not found so obviously clients (browser) won't need a new URL for 404.

Comment: Why are php tagged in this question?

Comment: im using it in a php project... maybe i should hahe user `apache` istead

Comment: It's not necessary @Paul edited your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.this-is-ma-new-404.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in your .htaccess.

==

for your own custom 404 use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /custom404.html
```

Comment: this might be awkward but, isn't there a way to send a 404 status with that?

Comment: Yes you can use `R=404` but URL redirect won't happen. Clients will get `HTTP status=404`

Comment: i'm looking to redirect `302` to a page and send a 404 header with that

Comment: well you can send only one HTTP code and with 404 external redirect won't happen.

Comment: u used `[R=301,L]`, shouldn't that be `[R=302,L]` ?

Comment: @Patrioticcow no 301 is right. cause that's the redirect. you can also do `[R, L]`